# Grails ElasticSearch plugin: Unexpected _problem_ processing bytes for class

Tags: grails, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I have installed Grails Elasticsearch plugin, but when I run a unit test just for creating a new instance of a domain class, I'm getting the following error in the console.

---

**OS**: ubuntu 14.04
**Grails**: 2.4.4
**ElasticSearch**: 1.5.0

---

```
elasticSearch.disableAutoIndex=true
elasticSearch.cluster.name = 'myInstanceName'
environments {
development {
    grails.logging.jul.usebridge = true
    /**
     * Possible values : "local", "node", "dataNode", "transport"
     * If set to null, "node" mode is used by default.
     */
    elasticSearch.client.mode = 'local'
}
test{
    elasticSearch.client.mode = 'local'  
}
```

---

```
SEVERE: Unexpected problem transforming call sites
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unexpected problem processing bytes for class
    at org.springsource.loaded.ConstantPoolChecker2.readConstantPool(ConstantPoolChecker2.java:196)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ConstantPoolChecker2.<init>(ConstantPoolChecker2.java:128)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ConstantPoolChecker2.getReferences(ConstantPoolChecker2.java:102)
    at org.springsource.loaded.MethodInvokerRewriter.rewrite(MethodInvokerRewriter.java:300)
    at org.springsource.loaded.MethodInvokerRewriter.rewriteUsingCache(MethodInvokerRewriter.java:156)
    at org.springsource.loaded.TypeRegistry.methodCallRewriteUseCacheIfAvailable(TypeRegistry.java:828)
    at org.springsource.loaded.agent.SpringLoadedPreProcessor.preProcess(SpringLoadedPreProcessor.java:321)
    at org.springsource.loaded.agent.ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.transform(ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.java:102)
    at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:655)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:765)
```